# Selenium IDE: Problem to record input value with dynamic security prefix

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to use selenium to record and click at item in a page with the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="HighlightRow(1, this, 3,"");" value="916242540932034325|628149" name="AID">
```

in Selenium IDE, recorded script:

```
click
//input[@name='AID' and @value='916242540932034325|628149']
```

However, the value 916242540932034325|628149
having security prefix "916242540932034325" which will change dynamically every time the page load.

**Problems:** My Recorded Script not able to RUN after page load due to the dynamic security prefix.

**Help:** Anyone have any suggestion for the problems I face above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `click //input[@name='AID' and contains(@value, '|628149')]`.  As long as that's a unique combination of NAME and VALUE, you'll get what you want.

Comment: FYI, since this is your first question: When you get the answer you like best, you should accept it by clicking on the big checkmark.